# GDB does not stop at main breakpoint

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to debug a segmentation fault on a remote machine using ssh. **It runs without a problem on my machine**. On the remote one it simply segfautls without printing anything, even if I put a debug print on the first line in main. I figured out which line causes the bug by shifting a `return 0` down `main()`.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::string dataset_name;
    if (argc > 1 ) {
        dataset_dir = ...
    }
    std::cout << "dataset name = " << dataset_name << std::endl;
    HDF5Dataset dset(dataset_name); // <-- this line causes the segfault
    ...
}
```

gdb does not trigger on any breakpoints. Things I've tried so far

1. `start` to apply an automatic breakpoint
2. `break main`, `run`
3. set breakpoint on main and all functions w/ global state (I have member functions which return their static local variable)
4. remove all global states + breakpoint on main

The problem is that not only does GDB skip my breakpoints, but the program also segfaults for some reason:

```cpp
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x592c6: file .../main.cpp, line 23.
Starting program: .../data_collector test
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffff7ff520, format=format@entry=0x555555aadf0f "can't locate ID", 
    ap=ap@entry=0x7fffff7ff680) at vfprintf.c:1320
1320    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Is there any other reason why I might be getting this segfault? I even searched for the `static` keyword to make sure there are no global states. It is also weird that even if there were any remaining SIOFs, putting `return 0` right before the buggy line should've still caused a segfault, but instead I get the debug print and the program exits normally.

P.S. Unfortunately due to the large size, I cannot provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Did you disable optimizations of the compiler? With optimizations it is plausible breakpoints aren't hit where you expect.

Comment: What is the output from `(gdb) where` at time of `SIGSEGV`? Your program may be crashing _before_ it reaches `main()`.

Comment: @bloody yes I did.

Comment: @EmployedRussian wow thanks. I'm a noob when it comes to gdb. the stack is 8k+ levels deep into the HDF5 library which is weird because the buggy line isn't even called yet. that same line works in a test I wrote both on the remote machine and on mine. HDF5 has its own version of exception handling which for some reason they thought is a good idea. it uses printf a lot.

Comment: If it runs without a problem on your machine does not mean there are no bugs in the program. Try to run it under Valgrind to check for memory related bugs.

Comment: It could be a stack overflow. Stack size can be increased, although if the problem is infinite recursion that will only delay another segmentation fault. What is the output of the shell command `ulimit -s` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it's 8192. I removed the "buggy line" and now the breakpoint is hit! How is it possible to receive errors for a line the debugger hasn't even hit yet? The HDF5Dataset is a wrapper for the HDF5 library (because it's impossible to use otherwise) but it does not do anything unless an object is created.

Comment: Try `ulimit -s 16384`. Some systems have a hard limit of 8192 by default; to go beyond that, you may have to become root to run the ulimit command and then in that same shell `su`  to your user. Or edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and then login again.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thank you for the response. it bug simply didn't make sense that I was getting a stack overflow without even calling the library's functions. so I dockerized it and it ran just fine ...